# Inline-block parent wrapping contents with height explicitly set to 0

Tags: css

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e3u7ba7o/7/)

In a dropdown with a container element set to `display: inline-block`, there is a label (always visible, toggles dropdown overlay), and the overlay element itself. I am setting the overlay container to `height: 0` and wishing to allow the overlay contents to exceed the height of the container, without affecting any parent elements. However, I am seeing some strange results - the overlay container is causing the parent of the dropdown to fully enclose the overlay contents too!

In the following HTML, `ib` = the inline block and `h0` = the `height:0` overlay container. See the jsfiddle demo to see it in action.

```
<div>
  Sort by this
  <span id="ib">
    <span>LABEL</span>
    <div id="h0">
      DROPDOWN<br />
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

I don't wish to use `position: absolute` on the overlay, as I would like the contents of the overlay to drive the final width of the label. Surprisingly, I can achieve the desired outcome with the following css:

```
#ib { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

I'm happy to use that workaround for now, but also interested in the "why" behind this bizarre effect.

Comment: sorry the question isn't very clear.

Comment: @digital-pollution I've updated the JSFiddle example to show the desired outcome in a 2nd example.

Comment: Do you want the html to remain the same or can we change it?

Comment: Why is the overlay container given "height:0". Removing that will fix the <hr> line. You might want to be more clear about what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: A dropdown menu works by having the overlay, or dropdown content, float on the page without affecting the elements underneath (a la <select>). The desired goal here is to achieve the same affect, I do not wish for the <hr> to be affected by the contents of the dropdown. See Narek's answer below for the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is about `vertical-align` rule for inline block elements. By default it `baseline`, here is some spec:

> Baseline: Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box.

See also:

> The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements, this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is their 'line-height'.

source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

and

> CSS assumes that every font has font metrics that specify a characteristic height above the baseline and a depth below it. In this section we use A to mean that height (for a given font at a given size) and D the depth. We also define AD = A + D, the distance from the top to the bottom.

source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-box-height

So your fix is ignore default inline-level block height setted via `line-height` and `font-size` by setting `vertical-align: top/bottom/middle/text-top/text-bottom` by your choice.

And fixed code:

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.overlay {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
 sort by this
 <span class="dropdown">
  <span>LABEL</span>
  <div class="overlay">
   DROPDOWN<br />
     DROPDOWN<br />
     DROPDOWN
  </div>
 </span>
</div>
<hr />
```